# Need to extract only a part of text on html page with imacros

Tags: html, imacros, extract, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract a part of text inside a Html page which is full of confusing tags.
I will try to explain better my problem:

Here is the source file of the html page
[HTML SOURCE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5ua5.jpg)

This is what i need to extract
[TEXT I NEED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqU6J.jpg)

So I made this macro by recording the actions and clicking on the area of interest in order to extract the second part of text I need:

```
FRAME F=2 
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

But of course it didn't work because this one extracts a huge amount of text that I don't need.

Is anyone here who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

do this for each specific div you need

```
FRAME F=2 
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:MagicZoomHeader EXTRACT=TXT
```

Comment: #EANF#

This is what I get when I run this exact code.

Comment: @ClaudioMartini sorry i realized it was a class answer updated.

Comment: this should be working in your case `FRAME F=2 
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:MagicZoomHeader&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT` if not please post your result perhaps something else casuing the issue

Comment: The iMacros Dialog gave me this result as Extraction Data:

`#EANF#`

Comment: Try `TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:MagicZoomHeader EXTRACT=TXT`. If it is still not working, you may need to experiment with changing the POS and FRAME values.

Comment: @iMacrosGuru _If it is still not working, you may need to experiment with changing the POS and FRAME values_ . TRUE

Comment: Okay so, now I can extract the first part of text I need.
About the second part, when I extract the text, it gaves me back this too 
`$('#piGal ul').bxGallery({
  maxwidth: 300,
  maxheight: 200,
  thumbwidth: 75,
  thumbcontainer: 300,
  load_image: 'ext/jquery/bxGallery/spinner.gif'
});




$("#piGal a[rel^='fancybox']").fancybox({
  cyclic: true
});
`
How can I delete all this part?

Comment: Nobody can help me?